# Put the washing in

Tags: antonyms

"Put the washing out."

The washing is done and take out all the washing on line.

> **"Put the washing in"**

All the washing is dried and take in the house.

Can the antonym "Put the washing in" as "Put the washing out."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major steps for dealing with laundry can be:

> **Put** the washing **in** *(to the washing machine)*.
>
> **Take** the washing **out** *(of the washing machine)*
>
> **Put** the washing **up** *(on the clothesline)*.
>
> **Take** the washing **down** *(from the clothesline)*.
>
> **Bring** the washing **into** *(the house)*.

Comment: I suppose you can also ***take** the washing in*, although where I live very few families hang wash up on clotheslines.  We just take it out of the dryer and fold it.

Comment: Can I ommit the word "the house" after "Bring the washing into."? @peter

Comment: Hmm... I have never used "washing" to refer to the laundry. Instead I use "laundry" for the machine, and "clothing" for the clothesline. Maybe it is AmE or just me.

Comment: @e12345678 You would simply say "Bring the washing/laundry **in**"